# How can I add option values in the select tag with PHP

Tags: php, function, mysqli, while-loop

I'm working with PHP and MySQL and I want to retrieve some data from db into a select html tag.

What I did was:

```
<select class='form-control select2' name='product_cat' style='width: 100%;'>
    ".get_cats()."
</select>
```

And the function `get_cats`  goes like this:

```
function get_cats(){
$get_cats = "select * from categories";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_cats);
$return = '';
while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
    $table_id = $row_cats['table_id'];
    $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
    $totalNumberOfProductsQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat = '" . $cat_id. "'";
    $catsProducts = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $totalNumberOfProductsQuery);
    if (!$catsProducts) {
       die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));
    }
    $totalProductsForCats = mysqli_num_rows($catsProducts);
    echo " 
        <option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>
    ";
    }
}
```

It simply grabs the data from database correctly but the problem is, it prints them out this way:

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYGpX.png)

While the Product Category field is empty and the options of select tag is going up the form field.

I guess this issue is because of the `while()` statement which I used at the function.

What is the alternative way of doing this function with another command? How can I place the option list correctly inside this function?

Thanks.

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars` for that

Comment: Try showing more code from the php form. From what I see it’s correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the way you are outputting the content.  When you put...

```
<select class='form-control select2' name='product_cat' style='width: 100%;'>
    ".get_cats()."
</select>
```

What you are expecting to happen is that you will take the return value of `get_cats()` and insert it into the HTML.  BUT in the `get_cats()` function, you aren't returning the value - you're echoing the values as you go along  What can happen is that this then gets mixed in rather than joined as you expect it to be (as you can see from your output).  Instead you should build up a string and return the full HTML back to the calling code so that can echo it out...

```
function get_cats(){
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_cats);
    $return = '';
    while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $table_id = $row_cats['table_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        $totalNumberOfProductsQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat = '" . $cat_id. "'";
        $catsProducts = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $totalNumberOfProductsQuery);
        if (!$catsProducts) {
           die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));
        }
        $totalProductsForCats = mysqli_num_rows($catsProducts);
        // Build up HTML
        $return .= " 
            <option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>
        ";
        }

    return $return;
}
```

A couple of other things.

- Rather than using `$GLOBALS['con']`, pass in the connection to the
  function, this is a preferred method of doing it.
- Look into prepared statements and bind variables.
- You could reduce the SQL to 1 statement, this means that just 1 SQL
  is used.

Comment: Would you please give me a refrence link on the proper way of passing connection to the function rather than using `$GLOBALS['con']`.

Comment: @traebeapaiso You don't know how to pass parameters to functions? `get_cats($con);`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Write the generated code into a string and **return** it at the end of the function. Further echo your function. Then it will work.